# Generators of 6th roots of unity group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be the group of 6th roots of unity. What are the generators of this group? What are the primitive 6th roots of unity?

I know that the primitive roots are $\frac{1}{2} \pm i\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$. Would these also be the generators of the cyclic group? I don't think they are but how would I determine the generator?

Comment: consider the hexagon that you can draw on the unit circle. if you take the 0, 2rd, 3rd or the 4th root, you can see that multiplying by themselves couldn't give you the whole group.

Comment: Basically if i is not coprime with 6, then the ith root would not be a generator.

Comment: Are you familiar with polar form for complex numbers?  Writing your roots this way will make identifying generators much easier.

Comment: @AustinC That is how I found the primitive roots. I just converted it to complex form. So would the generator be $cos \frac {k \pi}{3} + i sin \frac {k \pi}{3}$?

Comment: @Nid You can also write polar form as $e^{i\theta}$.  I'll post a more thorough hint as an answer.

Comment: Ok. So there should be 2 generators of the form $e^{i \frac{k \pi}{3}}$?

Comment: @Nid Yes, that's correct.

Comment: So what if we had say $e^{\frac{i k \pi}{3}}$ and $-e^{\frac{i k \pi}{3}}$?They would both generate all the values but the later in reverse order.

Comment: @Nid See the answer posted.  Note that neither $e^{i\frac{k\pi}{3}}$ nor $e^{-i\frac{k\pi}{3}}$ is necessarily a generator.  There are two particular values of $k$ for which $e^{i\frac{k\pi}{3}}$ is a generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're familiar with writing complex numbers in polar form, you can list the six sixth roots of unity as
\begin{equation}
e^0, e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}, e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}, e^{i\pi}, e^{i\frac{4\pi}{3}}, e^{i\frac{5\pi}{3}}.
\end{equation}
It is then easy to compute the subgroup generated by each of these.  For example,
\begin{equation}
\langle e^{i\frac{4\pi}{3}} \rangle = \lbrace e^{i\frac{4\pi}{3}}, e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}, 1 \rbrace,
\end{equation}
so $e^{i\frac{4\pi}{3}}$ is *not* a generator of $G$.  You can compute the subgroups generated by the other elements in the same way, and determine which roots give you all of $G$.  (Notice the similarity with modular arithmetic.)

Comment: So what about just $e^{\frac{i \pi}{3}}$ and $e^{\frac{-i \pi}{3}}$. Each successive power should derive each element of the group.

Comment: That's almost correct.  The root $e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}$ is a generator, but $-e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}} = e^{i\frac{4\pi}{3}}$, and thus is not a generator, as demonstrated in the answer.

Comment: Whoops. I changed my answer. I meant to put the negative next to the i.

Comment: Perfect.  Note that $e^{-i\frac{\pi}{3}}=e^{i\frac{5\pi}{3}}$.

Comment: Happy to help.  For what it's worth, on this site we say "Thanks" by upvoting/accepting helpful answers.

Comment: Oh I know. I just get distracted on occasion.